# Adding another Wine or "Virtual Drive" to removable USB and playing games from it

Tags: usb, wine, games, virtualization, playonlinux

I have recently installed 14.04 Ubuntu on my Chromebook using crouton. I am not much of a Ubuntu person, nor Linux. My Chromebook's capacity is 16 GB, and I only get to use about 8-9 GB. I already installed League of Legends using PlayOnLinux, so I am left with around 2 GB. I went to the store and bought a 32 GB flash drive to install my games on instead. How do I do this? I have the game installers, skyrim, gta, etc.. Just need to be able to install them on to the flash drive and be able to run them from the flash drive. (pretty much another wine C:/ on the flash drive). I made a letter in Drive Mapping to my USB Drive but when I install Skyrim it still installs it to the C on my computer's 16gb of memory :(

Thanks in advance, if this can't be done then just please tell me. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're using [separate Wine prefixes](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_can_I_run_two_programs_as_if_they_were_on_different_computers.3F) for each application managed by Wine/POL, because that would make the following much easier.

PlayOnLinux stores its Wine prefixes underneath `~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefixes/`. As with all files and directories, you can move any or all prefixes anywhere else and then place a symbolic link to the new location at their old place.

Let's assume, that you have a secondary storage drive mounted at `/media/mystorage`. There are now two alternatives:

- To move *all existing and future* Wine prefixes managed by POL:

  ```sh
   mv -T ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefixes /media/mystorage/wineprefixes
   ln -sT /media/mystorage/wineprefixes ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefixes
  ```
- To move *only some* Wine prefixes managed by POL (in this example called `warcraft`, `steam`, `LoL`)

  1. create a directory `/media/mystorage/wineprefixes`
  2. and run

     ```sh
      for f in warcraft steam LoL; do
          mv -T ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefixes/"$f" /media/mystorage/wineprefixes/"$f"
          ln -sT /media/mystorage/wineprefixes/"$f" ~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefixes/"$f"
      done
     ```

     You need to repeat this step for *every new* Wine prefix, that you want to move somewhere else.

  With some trickery you can

  1. create a new Wine prefix through POL by starting a new installation process,
  2. abort the installation process after creating the Wine prefix,
  3. move the prefix as described earlier, and
  4. only then install the Windows application by choosing to alter an existing prefix.

There's also an entry in the official PlayOnLinux wiki: [How to move PlayOnLinux virtual drives to another disk](http://wiki.playonlinux.com/index.php/How_to_move_PlayOnLinux_virtual_drives_to_another_disk)